# What exactly does "en baisse" mean?

Tags: sens

It's a rather long quote, but there is just one thing in there that I don't really understand:

> Dans cet épisode de notre programme, on va porter un regard sur la réaction internationale aux événements en Libye, sur les revues **en baisse** des prévisions des bénéfices aériens par l’Association Internationale des Transports Aériens en 2011, sur la démission du ministre Allemand de la défense suite aux allégations de Plagiat de certains parties de sa thèse de Doctorat, et enfin un compte rendu sur la cérémonie des Oscars.

I'm not exactly sure how I should understand the phrase **en baisse**. Well, I understand that they're going to take a look at the reviews of the forecasts for the profits that the International Air Transport Association is going to make in 2011 and I know that *en baisse* can roughly be translated into English as *falling*. But is it being used as an adjective modifying *reviews* or *profits*? Could you please help me make grammatical sense out of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je pense qu'il y a une erreur dans cette phrase ; en effet, "en baisse", modifie "revue", mais le sens de "revue" n'est pas "résultats" ; cela signifie "processus de révision" ;

> (TLFi) Action, fait d'examiner avec attention chacun des éléments d'un ensemble. Synon. inspection.

De nos jours, on emploie avec ce type de concept la préposition « **à** », ce qui donne « **revue à la baisse** » et ce qui signifie que dans le processus de révision

- 1/ soit on constate que la chose révisée est en baisse,
- 2/ soit que l'on opère une baisse vu des circonstances attenantes à la chose révisée.

Il n'y a ainsi pas d'ambiguïté possible dans le sens de penser qu'il pourrait s'agir de la revue elle-même qui serait « en baisse ». La locution prépositionnelle « à la baisse » modifie bien « revue » mais elle signifie « qui **indique** une baisse (de qqc) » pas « qui est en baisse ».

1. **Exemple du « 1/ » (baisse constatée)**

Les perspectives d’activité en Allemagne revues à la baisse

La Chambre de commerce et d'industrie allemande (DIHK) a fortement réduit ses prévisions de croissance pour cette année à 0,9%, contre 1,7% précédemment, du fait notamment des effets du ralentissement ...

2. **Exemple du « 2/ » (baisse fixée)**

La France revoit à la baisse ses objectifs de réduction de consommation d'énergie d'ici 2030

L'objectif passe de 20% à 17%, provoquant la colère des associations de défense de l'environnement. Selon les associations éc…

---

Dans le cas de la question,

> « sur les revues en baisse des prévisions des bénéfices aériens par l’Association Internationale des Transports Aériens en 2011 »,

qu'il me semble falloir comprendre comme

> « sur les revues **à la baisse** des prévisions des bénéfices aériens par l’Association Internationale des Transports Aériens en 2011 »,

la baisse est apparemment une **baisse constatée**, comme il s'agit d'une revue de prévisions.

Answer (score 2):

*En baisse* means indeed "declining", "lowering". In this quote, it modifies the noun *revues*. It means there has been some reviews of the forecast and these reviews have concluded that there is a decline.

Comment: Well, in English, if *falling* were to modify *reviews*, it would mean that the reviews themselves are falling which in our context here is completely nonsensical. I'm curious, how exactly would you translate that part?